# Define list inside data template for XAML

Tags: wpf, xaml, datatemplate

How do I define a data template that will show a list of string values, the list length is unknown (onyl know at runtime)?

Comment: How about a ListView?   The property you bind to needs to be a collection.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use some kind of [`ItemsControl`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.aspx) with its [`ItemsSource`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.itemssource.aspx) bound to the string list.